# Java EE patterns: authorisation and RESTful service implementation

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee, tomcat

I want to implement a basic RESTful service using Tomcat. The API requires authorisation before it can be used. Authorisation will be achieved by requesting an account 'resource' e.g

```
some.domain.com/rest/accounts?user=ABC&password=XYZ
```

If the credentials are valid, an appropriate account resource will be retuned as JSON or an empty response of type 403 will be returned.  After authorisation is performed, the client can then access the API (for example):

```
some.domain.com/rest/secure/bookings
some.domain.com/rest/secure/friends
```

However I feel lost with all the options for implementation. I know I want to use Spring, but Jackson seems simpler and easier for returning JSON objects.

Questions:

1. Should I implement a Spring Controller even though the class which uses Jackson is kind of a controller too? Or if I use Jackson is there no need for a Sping controller?
2. Should authentication be performed using Spring-Security, Tomcat filters, or AOP with Spring?

There seems to be so many ways to do things, but my priority is to keep things simple.

Comment: Probably the most brain-damanged way to perform authentication I have ever seen. Authentication is **not** the concern of the REST API but of the underlying framework/server with Basic, Digest, Negotiate, etc..

Comment: let alone the security flaw that is sending such sensitive information in the URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the most brain-damaged way to perform authentication I have ever seen. Authentication is **not** the concern of the REST API but of the underlying framework/server with Basic, Digest, Negotiate, etc. As duffymo already said, Spring Security is the most natural way to do so.

Comment: From the answers then, Spring Security for authorisation. Thank you. But what about the use of Jackson and the role of Controllers. Would using Jackson replace the need for an explicit Spring Controller?

Comment: You should have created two separate questions. Spring Sec will do both Authn and Authz. Jackson has nothing to do with controllers. You did not understand the purpose of Jackson. All is does ist serializing JSON to Java back and forth.

Comment: Sorry, I meant Jersey, not Jackson.

Answer (score 0):

Jackson is JSON serialization; I don't see what it has to do with authentication/authorization.

If you're already using Spring, Spring Security is a natural.

There's another viewpoint: keep it simple.  Basic auth and a database with usernames and encrypted, salted passwords wouldn't be hard to write.  A single DAO and you're good.

Yes, authentication/authorization are cross-cutting concerns.  The answer to the question of where best to put it depends on where you need to apply and consume it.  Tomcat filters require HTTP.  Will you authenticate at the controller or service layer?  Or both?  What about role based authorization?  That could be tricky.

Comment: It doesn't. I was just asking if it's OK to use Jackson with Spring when Spring can do JSON serialisation. Jackson seems easier to use, but it feels odd using another library when Spring can do it too.

Comment: Spring does not do any JSON serialization. Spring just uses a lib like Jackson, JAXB or XStream.

Comment: This is my bad. I mean Jersey, not Jackson!

Comment: Still not, see [here](http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/json.html).